# How to create 'normal' looking axis labels using latex in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have the following piece of code to create axis labels with German umlauts:

```
plt.xlabel('Daten')
plt.ylabel(r'$H\ddot{a}ufigkeit$')
```

which basically works, and prints the a-umlaut correctly, But the font of the x and y labels are now different, as the x label is printed in math mode. Changing the second line to

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\textrm{H\ddot{a}ufigkeit}$')
```

should work as far as I know (in order to create a `rm` like font instead of the math mode font), but gives a python error:

```
matplotlib.pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected end of math '$'
```

How can I fix this issue in order to have the same font on both axis, but with umlauts possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-math umlaut is `\"`:

```
plt.ylabel(r'H\"{a}ufigkeit')
```

If you need `\ddot` only put the `$` around that:

```
plt.ylabel(r'H$\ddot{a}$ufigkeit')
```

---

As an aside, the `\textrm` command only works in text mode.  The math-mode equivalent is `\mathrm`:

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{H\ddot{a}ufigkeit}$')
```

---

**UPDATE**

All of the above assume that you have told matplotlib to render with tex.  To do this, add the following at the top of your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. The label is now: H\"{a}ufigkeit instead of Häufigkeit. Maybe I need to setup something special for matplotlib...?

Comment: Have you told matplotlib to render with tex?